# Custom listview with edittext and button not working

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, custom-lists

I have created my own multi columned listview with an edittext and a button on each row. I am setting the tag value for each button to identify which row has been clicked. However in the onClick method I am trying to read in the value and convert it to an int. However the value of this edittext is always an empty string. Here is the code:

```
 wrapper.mySimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(Chores.this, chores, R.layout.parent_list_format, new String[]{"chore","child_name","points"},new int[]{R.id.value_name,R.id.child_name,R.id.point_value })
                {
                    @Override
                    public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                    {
                        //Setting the tag for each button of the list to the chore name
                        //to be able to identify which chore is to be claimed
                        final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.rate);
                        String names = ( v.findViewById(R.id.child_name)).toString();
                        names += ("::") + ( v.findViewById(R.id.value_name)).toString();
                        b.setTag(names);

                        //When one of the list buttons have been clicked
                        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                try {
                                    //Sends the chore data to the php file to update the database and reload page
                                    String names = (String) view.getTag();
                                    String child = names.substring(0,names.indexOf(":"));
                                    String chore = names.substring(names.lastIndexOf(":"), names.length()-1);
                                    **EditText points = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pointsGiven);
                                    int pointsGiven = Integer.parseInt (points.getText().toString());**
                                    Chore chores = new Chore(chore,pointsGiven,accountConnect.user.username,child);


                                    uploadChore(chores);
                                    startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Chores.class));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return v;
                    }
                };
```

The stars indicate the two lines in particular I am talking about. I'm guessing that it is reading this edittext when each row is being created and that's why it is always returning an empty string. Is there any way I can get the value of the edittext when the button is clicked?

this is the listview xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value_name"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/child_name"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/point_value"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"   />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="points"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pointsGiven"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text = "Rate"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In what layout is the `pointsGiven` id? You are currently trying to find it in the activity, and not the listview row layout

Comment: pointsGiven is in the listview row layout xml file

Comment: Then you need to use  `v.findViewById` instead

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do at `( v.findViewById(R.id.child_name)).toString();`? That isn't how you get the text from a Textview

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `EditText points` is located inside your row, you need to find it in your row View:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //your code
    EditText points = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pointsGiven);
    //your code
}
```

Comment: When I did this I got this error:                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: This means there is no EditText with the given `id` in your layout file. Maybe edit your original post & show the row layout?

Comment: @Amy - "view" is the Button which indeed does not have any child Views (--> NPE). You need "v" like cricket_007 said:  `EditText points = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pointsGiven);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //Setting the tag for each button of the list to the chore name
    //to be able to identify which chore is to be claimed
    final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.rate);
    String names = ( v.findViewById(R.id.child_name)).toString();
    names += ("::") + ( v.findViewById(R.id.value_name)).toString();
    b.setTag(names);
    EditText points = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pointsGiven);
    //When one of the list buttons have been clicked
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                //Sends the chore data to the php file to update the database and reload page
                String names = (String) view.getTag();
                String child = names.substring(0,names.indexOf(":"));
                String chore = names.substring(names.lastIndexOf(":"), names.length()-1);

                int pointsGiven = Integer.parseInt (points.getText().toString());**
                Chore chores = new Chore(chore,pointsGiven,accountConnect.user.username,child);


                uploadChore(chores);
                startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Chores.class));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Initialize **EditText** before the **onClick** in the adapter and try to get value of the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass to the on click the position of the item clicked then get the item :

```
                  //When one of the list buttons have been clicked

                    b.setTag(position);
                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                        Item item = getItem((int)view.getTag());
                    }
```